# sum rows in 3d numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Assume the following numpy is given:

```
myNP = np.array([[[2., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1.]],
              [[1., 2., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1.]],
              [[1., 1., 1.],
               [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

One has to find the weight of each point in each row in relation to the sum of the row.

in reference to the example above the expected result need to be:

```
[[[0.5  , 0.25 , 0.25 ],
  [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]],
 [[0.25 , 0.5  , 0.25 ],
  [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]],
 [[0.333, 0.333, 0.333],
  [0.333, 0.333, 0.333]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr_w = myNP / myNP.sum(-1)[...,None]

Out[161]:
array([[[0.5       , 0.25      , 0.25      ],
        [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]],

       [[0.25      , 0.5       , 0.25      ],
        [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]],

       [[0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333],
        [0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this to an ND case by specifying the axis:

```
axis = 2
reshape_axes = [*yNP.shape]
reshape_axes[axis] = -1
sol = yNP/yNP.sum(axis=axis).reshape(reshape_axes)
sol = sol.round(3)
```

output:

```
[[[0.5  0.25 0.25]
  [0.33 0.33 0.33]]

 [[0.25 0.5  0.25]
  [0.33 0.33 0.33]]

 [[0.33 0.33 0.33]
  [0.33 0.33 0.33]]]
```

The axis param in `np.sum` dictates what axis should be summed across (axis 0 is outermost lists, axis n innermost lists).  Here the summed result is reshaped so divide happens accordingly.